# Check a given row, and hide all the columns with blank cells - Office.js

Tags: vba, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have a macro (VBA) that checks a given row/range, and hide the column if the given cell is blank.

Is this possible to do in office.js?

```
Sub Hide()
  
Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("A1:Z1").Cells
        If c.Value = "" Then
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Don´t have many experience in programming. Vba or else.
For vba i can record macros and research some similar codes in forums.

But office.js is something i really don´t achieve.
Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [rowHidden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-rowhidden-member) and [columnHidden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-columnhidden-member) properties of the `Range` class in case of Office web add-ins.

The `columnHidden` property represents if all columns in the current range are hidden. Value is true when all columns in a range are hidden. Value is false when no columns in the range are hidden. Value is null when some columns in a range are hidden and other columns in the same range are not hidden.

The `rowHidden` property represents if all rows in the current range are hidden. Value is true when all rows in a range are hidden. Value is false when no rows in the range are hidden. Value is null when some rows in a range are hidden and other rows in the same range are not hidden.

Using Office JavaScript API, you can programmatically hide and unhide rows by updating the `rowHidden` property on the range object. The same can be applied to columns when using the `columnHidden` property. For example:

```
Excel.run(function (context) {

    // Hide rows 1-2 in 'Sheet1'
    var range = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("1:2");
    range.rowHidden = true;

    return context.sync()
        .then(function() {
            console.log("Rows 1-2 have been hidden.");
        });
}).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback and the time, but my problem is very different than the solution you propose. guess the way it´s to conitnue using vba :)

Comment: The question was - `Is this possible to do in office.js?`. So, yes - that is possible. You can use the technique described in my post.

Comment: But do you are sure that you can achieve that with columnHidden property?  Do you even try? I am not an expert in programming, as i said,  but as all my research and tries i can only achieve that with columnwidth = 0 because of the properties. I really appreciate your time, truly, but the way you answer...  it´s not easy to be in a forum, but that works both ways .. sincerely best wishes to you.

Comment: Let me know if you face with any specific issue.